# Casting Object to an interface and accessing the interface methods implemented elsewhere

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, takesscreenshot

We use the following code to take screenshots in selenium.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
File src = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(src, new File("D:\\TestNGScreenshots\\screenshot.png"));
```

Here is what I understood:

- TakesScreenshot is an interface that provides a method
  getScreenshotAs() to get screenshots.
- But WebDriver doesn't extend this interface.
- FirexfoxDriver class also doesn't implement this interface
- The getScreenshotAs() method is implemented in a separate class
  RemoteWebDriver which implements TakesScreenshot.

Here we are casting the driver object to another interface TakesScreenshot and we are using it's method getScreenshotAs() which is implemented in a completely different class.

So if we want to use an interface methods which were implemented in some classes  can we use them by casting our object (which was created from a class implementing to another interface) to that interface?

Also, if we create the driver like

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver()
```

We can't cast the Interface to the driver here. We have to use it like
TakesScreenshot ts = drvier
and then we can use the method getScreenshotAs(). Here also not sure what exactly happening?

Can someone explain please?

Thank you.

Comment: `FirexfoxDriver class also doesn't implement this interface` This is false. see here: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver.html

Comment: `We can't cast the Interface to the driver here` Can you explain what you mean by this?

Answer (score 1):

In your example you are casting from `WebDriver` interface to `TakesScreenshot` interface. You can always cast from one interface to another because the Java compiler can't tell if the reference defined by one interface doesn't hold an object that implements other interfaces. This check is deferred to runtime where you will get `ClassCastException` if it fails.

`FirefoxDriver` may not directly implement `TakesScreenshot` but it extends `RemoteWebDriver` which does. Because of that `FirefoxDriver` IS-A `TakesScreenshot` as per [the class javadocs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver.html). You can write following:

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
File src = driver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
```

Answer (score 0):

### TakesScreenshot

[TakesScreenshot](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/TakesScreenshot.html) is the public interface that provides a method [**`getScreenshotAs()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/TakesScreenshot.html#getScreenshotAs-org.openqa.selenium.OutputType-) to capture the screenshot and store it in the specified location and implements the following classes:

- FirefoxDriver
- ChromeDriver
- InternetExplorerDriver
- EdgeDriver
- OperaDriver
- SafariDriver
- EventFiringWebDriver
- RemoteWebDriver
- RemoteWebElement

This implies that the driver that can capture a screenshot and store it and is achieved by casting the driver instance into `TakesScreenshot` type instance.

As an example:

```
public static void takeScreenShot() throws IOException{
    String path = "./ScreenShots/";
    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)drive).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(path + "Subbu" + ".jpg"));
    System.out.println("Screenshot Taken");
}
```